# CSS селекторы JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

```
$(".group.select").not(".select-group").each(function () {
.....
});
```

Как написать такое же на JavaScript?

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. На нативном JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например используя [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
 var element = document.querySelectorAll('.group .select:not(.select-group)');

element.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```css
body{font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px}
.group {max-width:600px;background:#eee;padding:15px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="group">
<input type="checkbox" class="select" />check
<input type="checkbox" class="select" />check
<input type="checkbox" class="select" />check

<input type="checkbox" class="select select-group" />select-group
<input type="checkbox" class="select select-group" />select-group
<input type="checkbox" class="select select-group" />select-group
</div>
```